# pandas reading keys as values from a list of dictionaries by default

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

For some weird reason pandas DataFrame function does not seem to work as expected when providing it a proper list of dictionaries. Instead of reading the key as column name and the values as actual rows, it reads the key names as values for each row.

I've already tried several variations using .from_records and .from_dict without any result. Full code:

```
In [44]:
from zeep import Client
import pandas as pd
client = Client('http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl')

results = []
requests = [['IE', '6390845P'],['NL', '6390845P']]

for x in requests:
    results.append(client.service.checkVat(x[0],x[1]))

results

Out[44]:
[{
     'countryCode': 'IE',
     'vatNumber': '6390845P',
     'requestDate': datetime.date(2019, 5, 29),
     'valid': True,
     'name': 'BLACKNIGHT INTERNET SOLUTIONS LTD',
     'address': 'UNIT 12A, BARROWSIDE BUSINESS PARK, SLEATY ROAD, GRAIGUECULLEN CARLOW'
 }, {
     'countryCode': 'NL',
     'vatNumber': '6390845P',
     'requestDate': datetime.date(2019, 5, 29),
     'valid': False,
     'name': '---',
     'address': '---'
 }]

In [68]:

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df
​
```

Resulting in

```
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+---------+
|   | 0           | 1         | 2           | 3     | 4    | 5       |
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+---------+
| 0 | countryCode | vatNumber | requestDate | valid | name | address |
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+---------+
| 1 | countryCode | vatNumber | requestDate | valid | name | address |
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+---------+
```

Needs to be

```
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+---------+
|   | countryCode | vatNumber | requestDate | valid | name | address |
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+---------+
| 0 | IE          | 6390845P  | 2019/5/29   | true  | etc. | etc.    |
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+---------+
| 1 | NL          | 6390845P  | 2019/5/29   | false | ---  | ---     |
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+---------+
```

Comment: You could transpose the resulting dataframe. What is your desired output?

Comment: I get the desired output when I pass the dict to the dataframe function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. What version of pandas, python and what version of your OS are you running?

Comment: It seems to be an issue regarding the specific output of earlier functions. As soon as I copy the output of results and construct another variable with it, pandas seems to interpret it properly. Versions: python 3.6.3 jupyter 5.0.0 pandas 0.24.2 The full code for the results variable: `code from zeep import Client
import pandas as pd
client = Client('http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl')

results = []
requests = [['IE', '6390845P'],['NL', '6390845P']]

for x in requests:
    results.append(client.service.checkVat(x[0],x[1]))
    
results`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Assumption is the mother of all fuckups"

I found the problem. The zeep module is not returning a native python datatype where I assumed it was returning a standard dictionary.

```
type(results[0])

Out[46]:
zeep.objects.checkVatResponse
```

The module has a built in helper function to convert to a dictionary.

```
for x in requests:
    alpha = zeep.helpers.serialize_object(client.service.checkVat(x[0],x[1]))
    results.append(alpha)
```

The resulting list of dictionaries is properly recognized by Pandas, awesome!

Thanks for all the help and suggestions! You got me on the right track and thaught me yet another valuable Python lesson.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is a little bit wrong, the constructor of DataFrame doesn't take as argument whatever array you want, it can receive

> ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame

So if you want to use a dictionary this is the correct way to use it:

```
>>> d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

This is the example provided by doc.

I think you should specify in your dictionary first a column (e.g. 'col1') and then an array containing values, so your dicionary seems not to be well formed:
Your `result` should be something like:

```
{
'countryCode' : ['IE','NL'], 
'vatNumber':[6390845P,6390845P], 
'requestDate': [datetime.date(2019, 5, 29),datetime.date(2019, 5, 29)], 
'valid':[True, False], 
'name': ['BLACKNIGHT INTERNET SOLUTIONS LTD', '---'], 
'address': ['UNIT 12A, BARROWSIDE BUSINESS PARK, SLEATY ROAD, GRAIGUECULLEN CARLOW', '---']
}
```

Or you can use different functions like others have suggested! I hope this helps